# Duplicata em pergunta diferente

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, perguntas-duplicadas

A pergunta se difere em alguns detalhes, na comunidade em inglês não acontece problemas como este.

[Comando em Javascript de copiar e colar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71526/ctrl-c-com-onclick-quando-apertar-uma-div-ou-um-a?noredirect=1#comment146679_71526)

Preciso literalmente utilizar o comando ctrl C, e não "Maneira cross-browser de copiar texto para a Área de Transferência"

Quero um comando JavaScript que faça isto, apenas isto. Se o browser não suportar simplesmente posso jogar em um textfield.

E eu não preciso entrar em detalhes sobre o meu projeto, algumas pessoas ao invés de responder a pergunta fica querendo mudar a pergunta.

Eu quero algum comando que copie e cole conteúdo em javascript, não estou me importando se funciona em todos os browser ou não.

Se não responderem a pergunta sou obrigado a perguntar em outra comunidade que saiba fazer uma comunidade crescer ao invés de fazer uma comunidade com respostas pela metade e muito específicas. Além disto aquela pergunta tem título difícil de achar e não tem uma resposta válida.

A minha pergunta é simples e objetiva. Eu quero algo simples. Por favor me ajudem com uma resposta.

Comment: Seria interessante entender um pouco mais sobre o problema, até pra conseguir dar a melhor resposta possível e fazer a melhor melhor avaliação possível da pergunta.
Comentei na pergunta pra entender se seu problema pode ser resolvido de alguma outra forma que não usando o `clipboard`.
Isso é fundamental para pensar em formas diferentes para resolver o mesmo problema.

Comment: Se ninguém soube responder aquela pergunta (e assumo que ninguém ainda sabe, pois eu perguntei há mais de 1 ano e até agora ninguém respondeu) como você espera que alguém "simplesmente" responda a sua? É a mesma dúvida: como copiar algo programaticamente pra área de transferência... Se você "não se importa se funciona em todos os browsers ou não", então indique na sua pergunta qual browser específico te interessa, aí quem sabe alguém tem uma resposta específica pro seu caso (e aí não será duplicata). Eu sou da opinião que é duplicata sim, pelo menos a parte de copiar.

Comment: Quanto a colar, ok, não é duplicata, e merece sim uma pergunta separada. Minha sugestão é editar sua pergunta de acordo com o que você prefere (copiar/colar em um browser específico? somente colar?) e tentar chamar a atenção à pergunta original, achar algum especialista que saiba respondê-la, sei lá. Eu colocaria uma recompensa nela, mas não acho que tenha ninguém dentro do SOpt (quiçá no SOen, pois pesquisei lá também) nesse momento que saiba respondê-la. Se eu estiver enganado, tanto melhor...

Comment: @mgibsonbr agora eu fiquei perplexo, realmente seus argumentos estão me convencendo. Do ponto vista a falta de clareza me confundiu, então talvez seja realmente uma duplicata.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu acho que o AP e eu queremos a mesma coisa: programaticamente copiar algo pra área de transferência (e embora não esteja explícito nem na minha pergunta nem na dele, "colar" também, i.e. pegar o que está na área de transferência e usar num código JS). Infelizmente pra ambos, esse tipo de coisa é normalmente proibido por questões de segurança, alguns browsers chegam a pedir permissão ao usuário, mas a maioria bloqueia direto. Entretanto, se o que o AP quer (e isso não está claro na pergunta) é um ctrl c / ctrl v "interno" (dentro da própria página), então é factível.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Obrigado pelo retorno, me referi a falta de clareza do autor aqui me confundiu - my bad :( - editei a resposta só para ele ter uma maior compreensão do funcionamento da comunidade. Vamos esperar, mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: @mgibsonbr fiz um comentário justamente pra tentar enteder a necessidade dele, pra ver alguma alternativa, infelizmente não tive retorno, sendo na mesma página existem algumas possibilidades, mas é necessário entender um pouco mais a dúvida, considero esta pergunta tanto duplicata quanto não clara o suficiente para uma boa resposta.

Comment: A questão é que preciso da função de cópia do ctrl c mesmo, pois o conteúdo não será utilizado apenas na página, ele será feito para facilitar a cópia de conteúdo do site. Logo não dá para simular uma cópia. Teria que ser realmente ctrl-c. Deve ter alguma forma de fazer isto, não e possível. Na comunidade em inglês tem um tópico que responde isto, porém não funciona em todos os navegadores. 

Não acho que precisa especificar o browser que quero, pois para os browser que não suportam eu vou fazer algum esquema alternativo que a pessoa copiaria através de um textbox.

Comment: O Felipe colocou uma nova pergunta: (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72910/129) Parece que assim a disussão fica completa. Vou dar `+1` na nova e sugiro que a outra fique como está, fechada. (cc/ @mgibsonbr)

Comment: @Sergio Me parece essencialmente a mesma pergunta, mas deixa estar: já que o AP não quer contextualizar mais, respondi literalmente ao que foi perguntado, tomando as liberdades necessárias para tal.

Comment: @FelipeJorge entendi o seu caso, é muito simples de reabrir a pergunta, complete com um uma frase assim, não quero usar a solução clipboard gostaria de outra solução, e pronto vou votar para reabrir e postar uma resposta que talvez seja a solução que deseja ;)

Comment: E fique tranquilo, já fecharam minhas perguntas, fiz o mesmo que você, vim no meta e expliquei e argumentei, e sim as vezes precisei reformular a pergunta e foi reaberta em seguida

Answer (score 7):

fui eu que fechei a pergunta como duplicada.
Não foi por mal, é para nos ajudar a ter o conteúdo do site organizado.

Os comentários do @mgibsonbr explicam bem o que penso também, não vou repetir. Se quiseres editar a pergunta e ser mais específico podemos re-abrir e juntar forças para encontrar uma boa resposta que seja útil a ti e aos próximos que aqui venham à procura de resolver o mesmo problema.

Eu votei para fechar e voto certamente para abrir se editares a pergunta e referir um problema / objetivo diferente do que a outra pergunta procura resolver.

Comment: Hmmm... o sistema apagou automáticamente a primeira linha do meu post que dizia "Olá Filipe,". Deixo aqui como comentário...

Comment: A pergunta pode ser útil para a comunidade pois ela dá a resposta de usar um comando em Javascript para copiar conteúdos. Coisa que na outra pergunta é muito específica, Pois funcionaria em todos os browsers. (Tendo que usar plugins ou algoritmos mais complexos)

Acredito sim que esta rigorosidade pode atrapalhar a comunidade, pois podem deixar pessoas com dúvidas de como fazer este comando JavaScript sem ser cross browser.

Perguntas mais raras tem mais tendências a ser marcadas como duplicatas, mesmo não sendo iguais.

Comment: A pergunta é diferente pois se eu fosse dar uma recompensa para a outra pergunta eu teria que mudar a pergunta do colega, pois eu não quero cross browser. 

Além do mais, o termo clipboard apesar de ser utilizado no Windows para copiar ele vai além do comando ctrl c. Poderia ser qualquer método de cópia.
Apenas quero que funcione em algum dos browsers. Não precisa ser um algoritmo perfeito, apenas quero o comando que faz a cópia do conteúdo. 

Além do mais o termo utilizado da outra pergunta é difícil de encontrar e está mal formulada. O termo Clipboard n

Comment: @FelipeJorge Eu não acho que esteja mal formulada, mas eu sou suspeito pra falar (já que sou o autor da pergunta). Eu uso *ambos* os termos "área de transferência" (pt) e *"clipboard"* (en) justamente pra cobrir ambas as frentes (o corpo da pergunta ainda contém os termos "copiar", *"copy"* e *"cut"*). De todo modo, continuo sem entender seu posicionamento: você diz que "não precisa ser cross browser", mas não quer especificar um browser! Como responder? Se você editar sua pergunta de modo a ficar realmente diferente da minha e respondível, eu dou o voto de reabrir na hora.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Por ora, vou fazer o seguinte: vou editar minha própria pergunta para "ficar mais fácil de achar" (se você acha que escrever explicitamente ctrl c ajuda, blz, faço isso), pra ficar mais fácil de responder (eu continuo querendo algo cross browser, mas nada impede que alguém dê uma resposta parcial - um dos comentadores chegou inclusive a sugerir Flash), e colocar uma recompensa nela. Se tiver alguém na comunidade que sabe a resposta, certamente vai aparecer (espero). Mas eu duvido, pois como já mencionei, há questões de segurança envolvidas, não é algo tão simples como pensa...

Comment: Sua pergunta ainda é cross browser, eu só quero o comando javascript que copia e cola. Adapte a sua pergunta a se encaixar com a minha. Ou se não não é duplicata.

Answer (score 6):

O @mgibsonbr fez um apontamento, talvez seja uma duplicata, então está resposta agora é apenas para o entendimento do que significa fechar/duplicar e o funcionamento da comunidade.

<s>Realmente a *pergunta/resposta* referenciada para a sua responde apenas metade, já que no seu caso é o processo de *copiar* e depois *colar*.</s>

No momento não posso responder porque está bloqueada, mas logo desbloqueia.

Quero deixar uma coisa clara pra ti amigo, ninguém está tentando atrapalhar o crescimento da comunidade, *fechar* ou *suspender* não são coisas "ruins" e assim como usuários do *SOpt* novos podem se enganar, usuários mais experientes também tem o direito de se enganar, por exemplo fechar por engano uma pergunta.

As perguntas podem ser Fechadas e Reabertas a qualquer momento e justamente por isto existe o META, para resolvermos enganos :)

Espero logo poder lhe enviar uma resposta.

Comment: Aquela pergunta é diferente da minha, o requerimento cross browser faz a pergunta totalmente diferente. Somente o comando javascript  é necessário. Apenas coloque o comando javascript e coloque em baixo em quais navegadores funciona. (não precisa ser cross browser)

Ou se não edite a outra pergunta para se adaptar as minhas necessidades.

Comment: @FelipeJorge então não foi pela pergunta, mas pela resposta que eu imaginei que pude-se ser uma duplicidade, se bem que eu tenho uma resposta diferente pra sua pergunta, eu queria muito responder. Eu votei por reabrir, infelizmente mais pessoas tem que votar para reabrir também. Estou aguardando.

Comment: @FelipeJorge Você quer copiar o texto do div ou a formatação também?